# Correct path in maven-archetype-webapp

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I might ask a silly question but I tried all the options and didn't find anyone which worked out. There is intellijIDEA project based on maven-archetype-webapp. It has standard folders structure:

- java classes are located in `src/main/java`
- jsp/css are under `src/main/webapp`
- Spring configuration files are in `src/main/resources`
- web.xml is in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`

The issue is that I can't provide the path to any folder in this structure. For example: I need to provide the path to controllers folder in
`<context:component-scan base-package="org.financespring.web"/>` (assuming that `org.financespring.web` underlies `src/main/java`). There is no way to provide the appropriate path (`src/main/java/org/financespring/web`, `main/java/org/financespring/web`, `java/org/financespring/web`, `org/financespring/web` - these pathes are incorrect). Please give me an advice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guys, anyone! Please give an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it. I had to mark root folder (click on the folder that is root and chose **Mark Directory As / Root Folder**). Quite easy)